# mysql SUM until value is reached

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a website for a 'walking challenge', which has a table that logs miles walked.

The target is 2105 miles (Newcastle, UK to Istanbul).

On the home page i have a leaderboard which currently shows the 5 teams who have racked up the most miles.

I am using the following query to achive this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(log.distance) AS l, 
    log.*, 
    team.*
FROM 
    team
RIGHT JOIN 
    log ON team.teamname = log.teamname                             
GROUP BY 
    log.teamname
ORDER BY 
    l DESC
```

However i want this leaderboard to show the 5 teams that finished first rather than who have walked the furthest. ie, the teams who reached 2105 miles first.

The current website can be viewed [here](http://activenewcastle.com/walkingchallenge/)

Comment: Please post the DDL of the log and team tables. Your question is impossible to answer without knowing what timestamps you saved *(and you'll have to forgive me for not blindly clicking any links presented)*

Comment: how do you keep track of time, and in what table?

Comment: I currently keep track of time using a simple timestamp (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), in the log table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a nullable `completedDate` field to the table and populate it whenever someone completes the race. Order by the completed date.

There'd be no way to order by who finished first otherwise.

Comment: i think there is a way if there's a timestamp in the log table. The site seems to be live and working already, and the database looks to be pretty well populated. so i think it's too late now to add a new field

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't click on the link and notice that some people have already completed the challenge. If the timestamp exists, then that's possible. However, I would still create the column and then write a script to populate it currently from the log's timestamp. Then set and use the new field for all future completions.

Comment: Cool, i'll do that, the challenge runs for 16 weeks at a time, so this should work next time around. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a timestamp field that gets the current time everytime a team enters the number of miles it has walked, you could do domething like this:

```
    SELECT 
        SUM(log.distance) AS l,
        MAX(log.timestamp) AS t,
        log.*, 
        team.*
    FROM 
        team
    RIGHT JOIN 
        log ON team.teamname = log.teamname                          
    GROUP BY 
        log.teamname
    WHERE
        l >= 2105
    ORDER BY 
        t ASC
```

Keep in mind that this will only work if you don't allow a team to add extra miles after completing the target distance.
If they are able to add extra miles after completing the target, let me know, and i'll try looking for another query

Comment: Hi, yea the teams can still add miles after they have reached the total :(

Comment: Rocket Ronnie: ok, in that case i think Chucks solution is the simplest. I believe there is a way in sql to only sum results untill a condition is met, but i'm not realy an sql expert, so i'd stick with Chucks solution if i where you :)